# RESTful Express Mongoose & Backbone - Backbone model.remove() not working

Tags: ajax, node.js, backbone.js, express, mongoose

I'm developing a Node app using Express, Mongoose and Backbone with Marionette.

All routes are working well except the delete route.

If I call this.model.destroy, I always get this error:

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/user 404 (Not Found)
```

The 404 is returned in Express's delete route, like if Express didn't support it, but I've seen numerous examples across the web using it.

Here's my setup:

---

Mongoose Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    name: String,
    email: String,
    age: Number
});

User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

---

ExpressJS Route:  (not working)

```
app.del('/api/user/:id', user.remove);
```

OR

```
app.delete('/api/user/:id', user.remove);
```

This route is called by backbone model.destroy(), but returns error 404.

---

ExpressJS user.js controller:  (works but is not reached because of the 404 before)

```
exports.remove = function(req, res)
{
  var id = req.params.id;

  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user) 
  {
      user.remove(function(err) 
      {
          if(err) res.json(err);
          res.json('all good');
      });
   });
};
```

---

BackboneJS Model

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "_id",
    url: '/api/user/',
});
```

---

BackboneJS client View

```
var UserView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend(
{
    template: Handlebars.compile($('#userView').html()),
    events: 
    {
        'click .delete-button': 'deleteUser'
    },
    deleteUser: function(event)
    {
        this.model.remove();
    }
});
```

---

I always get this error:

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/user 404 (Not Found)
```

---

HOWEVER it works if I use this direct ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url:'/api/user/' + this.model.id,
  type: 'DELETE',
  success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
  {

  }
});
```

---

So, why does this work if I call the route via Ajax, if Backbone internally also uses Ajax? Why does Backbone fail to make such a simple model.destroy()?

Is there a way to configure Backbone Model.destroy method to work well like the Ajax example above? Thanks

Comment: it looks like the id of the model is not set when you do the DELETE request. Shouldn't the HTTP DELETE request url be, for example, http://localhost:3000/api/user/35 where 35 is the id of the user? It doesn't look like the id of the user is being sent...

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Backbone model.remove() was not sending the id because I was using "url" in this way:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/users',
    //...
});
```

That will tell Backbone to use exactly /users as the URL for all actions.

To ensure sending the id using "url", one can use a function:

```
url: function() { 
    return '/list_items/' + encodeURIComponent(this.id) 
}
```

Or even better use "urlRoot" instead of "url", let the default "url" function add the id:

```
urlRoot: '/users'
```

Working like a charm with urlRoot

Comment: yeah, urlRoot is even simpler. you don't need to define url as a function if you use urlRoot. defining url as a function is better reserved for more complex urls that use query params.